remote application child route not working - Angular
in microfrontend - i am exposing  one module suppose m1 and this m1 have 5 route it's working fine while i am running this child application individually but after integrate as microsite in shell application then child application route not working, how shell application know about this m1 routes after integrate  shell application override route of child app??

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
